# DNS Resolver for Windows over TCP

Tags: networking, dns, tcp, udp

I know that DNS uses UDP with Port **53** for DNS queries.
However, at my place sometimes UDP requests are blocked and DNS fails.
I know that there is protocol for **DNS over TCP** and many public DNS servers (such as Google's 8.8.8.8 ) supports it.
Is there a way or a DNS resolver that could make DNS requests over TCP for windows.

Comment: That's probably not the right solution to your issue. The right solution is probably to figure out how or why port 53 is getting blocked and fix it.

Comment: DNS reverts to TCP when the response packet gets over a certain size.  It isn't an alternative transport, it is part of the main protocol.  So no, you cannot force TCP for normal queries.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Its not in my control. Network Admins do that on campus.

Comment: @Paul How does this works then: [DNS2SOCKS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dns2socks/). I use this with Tor, which I suppose is TCP only!

Comment: SOCKS5 supports UDP, specifically for DNS (though I assume it can do other things).  It just means that the DNS lookup is done at the server end, rather than the client end.

Comment: @Richa Then ask them what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If port 53 requests are being block by a firewall, there is a reason for it.  Viruses and Malware often use directed DNS queries to find their command-and-control servers, so *that's a very good reason* for an ISP to block port 53 except to their own servers or select public DNS services.  They can catch this garbage and inform users they are infected.

You need to contact your network administrator and ask for their DNS servers and use those.  (*Especially* since you're running Windoze.)

Answer (score 1):

Configure the windows Adapter Interface for localhost 127.0.0.1

UDP to TCP Socks Proxy Server For UDP DNS Packets

```
DNS2SOCKS.exe /la:socks.log 127.0.0.1:1080 8.8.8.8:53 127.0.0.1:53
```

**Further Reading**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082423/dns-through-socks-proxy-how-do-i-change-windows-settings-for-domain-resolution

http://dns2socks.sourceforge.net